# How to update props, when state changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a method in my parent component of a weather app to update the unit (Metric/Imperial).

```
changeUnit = async (unit) => {
    const forecasts = { ...this.state.forecasts };
    forecasts['unit'] = unit = unit === 'Metric' ? 'Metric' : 'Imperial';
    this.setState({ forecasts });        
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="weather-data">
            <WeatherOverview 
                currentWeather={this.state.currentForecast} 
                changeUnit={this.changeUnit} 
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This gets passed down to the weather over component, which then passes it down to the currentWeatherComponent

```
return (
            <div className="weather-overview">
                <CurrentWeatherData weather={this.props.currentWeather} status={this.props.currentWeather.isLoaded} changeUnit={this.props.changeUnit}/>
            </div>
        )
```

In the CurrentWeatherComponent I have a variable called unit, which takes the unit from props via state.

```
class CurrentWeatherData extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        const unit = this.props.weather.unit;
        {console.log(unit)}
    }
   }
```

When state updates, the unit variable does not. How can I change the unit variable?

Comment: It's updating state though. How would I resolve it?

Comment: I don't think that is correct

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Solved it, I was updating the wrong state object fm